# Frenchspacing not working in footnote

Tags: spacing, footnotes, frenchspacing

I have

```
\footnote{\textit{Difesa della povera gente}, in: \textit{L’attesa}, p. 81; cfr. \textit{Ero disoccupato e mi hai trovato 
lavoro}, in: Giovagnoli, \textit{op. cit.}, pp. 232--233.}.
```

which produces the following result:

[image]

I am using \frenchsetting, as you can see in the text (after the period).
However, the interword spacing in the footnote is not correct. it is too much.
I could use \hbox, but I will not get correct hyphenation.
Any hint?

Comment: It's a problem of poor paragraphing, due to impossibility of finding better line breaks, so the interword spaces are stretched. I suggest you to load `microtype`, which does wonders for problems like these.

Comment: It seems quite curious to type the reference information by hand: don't you want to use a package like `biblatex` instead?

Comment: @pluton - Do you actually know that the author entered the footnote material by hand in the original form of his/her document? For a *minimal* working example, of course, it's necessary to provide the material by hand, unless one wanted to make the example not-so-minimal...

Comment: @Mico - It was just a comment that may prove useful.

Comment: How did you load frenchspacing? With `usepackage[french]{babel}`?

Comment: @pprBy using \frenchspacing command in the pramble

Comment: @pluton The author did not like any style we provided (bibtex, jurabib and so on). So, we put the ref. by hand.

Comment: actually, i am pretty sure that `\frenchspacing` *is* in effect, otherwise the spaces after "p." and "cfr." in the first line would be wildly larger than the spaces between the first few words.  the spaces are just slightly larger, which is an optical effect due to the fact that the periods have almost no height.  the real problem is poor paragraphing, as noted by egreg.

Comment: What does it meand "poor paragraphing"? Is it my fault? If yes I do not understand how to do good paragraphing: I just typed the sentence of the footnote as it appear.